# Do Azure Cosmos DB consistency levels only make sense in multi-regional setup?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, consistency

Do I need to bother about consistency level if I'm not going to use Cosmos DB in 2 or more regions (i.e. I'm only going to use a Cosmos DB database in a single region)? Or are the consistency levels important even in a single region, because Cosmos DB maintains several replicas in every region automatically and the "consistency" is the consistency between all these automatic replicas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, consistency levels also make sense when you have only 1 region because, indeed, cosmos db has replicas inside each individual region (so if you have only 1 region you would have several replicas of your cosmos db inside this region).

And, for example, eventual consistency means write\read to a single replica and do not wait for acknowledgement from another replicas (faster\less RU).

Comment: What if you only have an Cosmos DB account in a single region, does it makes sense to chose other than the default Session? I have read that replica writes within a single region happens blazingly fast, like 1 ms

Comment: well, it depends on your goal. if you do 99.9% reads - eventual consistency will be faster to query